# Как решить проблему с переполнением /tmp в Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

На сервере с Ubuntu хостится сайт. Раз в две недели стабильно падает с ошибкой

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_3f0_0.MYD' (Errcode: 28)

Я так понимаю, что забивается папка /tmp. Причем перезапуск VPS не помогает. Только `rm -r /tmp`.

Можно как-нибудь регулировать подобное поведение, чтобы предотвратить падение сайта?

```
root@185:/home/admin# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda3       29G   21G  6.1G  78% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            492M  4.0K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           101M  384K  100M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            501M     0  501M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvda1      190M  184M     0 100% /boot
root@185:/home/admin# df -h tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda3       29G   21G  6.1G  78% /
root@185:/home/admin#
```

---

из комментария:

```
$ stat -c '%A' /tmp
drwxrwxrwx
```

Comment: а что выдаёт `$ stat -c '%A' /tmp`?

Comment: Выдает drwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $ stat -c '%A' /tmp
>   drwxrwxrwx

это неправильно для каталога `/tmp`. из `man chmod`:

> this is called the restricted deletion flag for the directory, and is commonly found on  world-writable  directories like /tmp

добавьте флаг *restricted deletion*:

```
$ sudo chmod +t /tmp
```

---

я не уверен в том, что именно в этом проблема, но «зацепили» слова про «помогает только удаление `/tmp`» и отсутствие упоминания про то, каким образом каталог воссоздаётся.

---

в общем и целом я бы порекомендовал для выявления проблемы начать с мониторинга свободного пространства на разделе, где находится каталог `/tmp`. как-нибудь так (раз в пол-часа добавляется строчка с датой и выводом программы `df` в файл `~/mm`):

```
$ while true; do sleep 1800; { echo -n "$(\date) "; df /tmp | tail -n 1; } >> ~/mm; done
```

команду эту лучше, конечно, запустить в сеансе `screen`-а (или `tmux`-а), чтобы она не прервалась при обрыве связи с сервером.